# Fatal error Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_assoc() in php SQL

Tags: php, mysqli

i'm having problem with my code

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_assoc(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\jakubb\zadanie1.php:6 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\jakubb\zadanie1.php(6): mysqli_fetch_assoc(false) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\jakubb\zadanie1.php on line 6

Code:

```php
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root',"",'pracownicy');
$sql="SELECT imie,timestampdiff(year,urodzony,'2021.12.31') from pracownicy";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
mysqli_close($conn);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "<a>"."Imie: ".$row["imie"].", wiek: ".$row["timestampdiff(year,urodzony,'2021.12.31')"]."<br></a>";
}
?>
```

Comment: No idea if it makes any difference here, but normally, MySQL uses the date format: `Y-m-d`, not `Y.m.d`

Comment: @M.Eriksson FYI separator should be irrelevant